# Unable to change the Color of the Menu option on the Android Toolbar

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, android-toolbar

been trying to change the color of the menu items that appear on the Toolbar.

Here is my **menu xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:orderInCategory="100"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/always"
        android:title="Always"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="101"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/never"
        android:title="Never"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:orderInCategory="102"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/ifroom"
        android:title="If Room"
        android:orderInCategory="103"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/always1"
        android:title="Always1"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="104"/>

</menu>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I've tried using the style options but I cannot figure out how to change the color. The `actionMenuTextColor` & `android:actionMenuTextColor` do not solve the problem. It still appears black. Which looks untidy on my blue background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Turns out I was inheriting the wrong theme! This works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line in **styles.xml**

```
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
```

and add this

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
<item name="android:itemBackground">@color/skyBlue</item>
```

**Complete code :**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/skyBlue</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: @VarunJoshi did you change the color name.

Comment: yes, made no difference :( Did not realize this would be so complicated

Comment: @VarunJoshi try to `clean` and `rebuild` the project.

Comment: @Ironman You added this in the styles.xml in the Apptheme section, right?

Comment: @Ironman I copypasted the entire code from your edit still no luck. Sorry, just a beginner in Android

Comment: @VarunJoshi I give `red` and `skyBlue` color did you change it or not.

Comment: @Ironman yes i did. added the values to my colors.xml and used them in styles.xml

Comment: @VarunJoshi did you clean the project. and if that not work then close android studio and restart it again.